# MySQL display values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help. Basically, I have 4 tables namely: **posts**, **users**, **friendship** and **favourite_posts**.

I need to select all posts of a user and his friends' posts. Also I need to include in the result set the favourite posts.

So far this is what I've done:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.title, p.post_id, p.user_id, fp.post_id
 FROM posts AS p
 LEFT OUTER JOIN favourite_posts AS fp
 ON p.post_id = fp.post_id
 JOIN users AS u
 ON p.user_id = u.user_id
 LEFT JOIN friendship AS f
 ON p.user_id = f.user_id
 OR p.user_id = f.friend_id
 WHERE p.user_id = 1
 OR f.friend_id = 1
 AND fp.user_id = 1
 AND f.status = 1
```

**SCHEMA:**

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(`post_id` int, `title` varchar(11), `user_id` int);

INSERT INTO posts
(`post_id`, `title`, `user_id`)
VALUES
(1, 'Hello World', 1),
(2, 'Hola Mundo', 2),
(3, 'Ola Mundo', 1),
(4, 'Hi Mundo', 4),
(5, 'Test 1', 1),
(6, 'Test 2', 2),
(7, 'Test 3', 3),
(8, 'Test 4', 4),
(9, 'Test 5', 1),
(10, 'Test 6', 2);


CREATE TABLE users
(`user_id` int, `name` varchar(7));

INSERT INTO users
(`user_id`, `name`)
VALUES
(1, 'George'),
(2, 'Michael'),
(3, 'Learns'),
(4, 'To Rock');


CREATE TABLE friendship
(`friendship_id` int, `user_id` int, `friend_id` int, `status` int);

INSERT INTO friendship
(`friendship_id`, `user_id`, `friend_id`, `status`)
VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 1),
(2, 1, 3, 1),
(3, 2, 1, 1),
(4, 2, 4, 1);


CREATE TABLE favourite_posts
(`fp_id` int, `post_id` int, `user_id` int);

INSERT INTO favourite_posts
(`fp_id`, `post_id`, `user_id`)
VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 2, 1),
(4, 2, 4);
```

You can test my SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47206/6)

In my example, I need to get user # 1's all posts (including his friends' and favourite posts)

User 1 has 4 posts

User 2 has 3 posts

User 3 has 1 post

And User 1 has 2 favourite posts

The result should have total count of 8 (i.e. 8 posts) but I'm getting only 5. What do you think is wrong with my query? I would gladly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it works on the whole selected row. SELECT DISTINCT(p.title), p.post_id is the same as SELECT DISTINCT p.title, p.post_id, which is the same as SELECT DISTINCT p.title, (p.post_id)...

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` will do the trick

Comment: @cyadvert where will I put the GROUP_CONCAT() ?

Comment: @jarlh oh yeah thanks. I corrected my query. But i still get 5 posts

Comment: Does this have to be done in one query?

Comment: Your current query doesn't quite capture that the post is either by user 1 or a friend of user 1. Also, you don't want a WHERE clause on the favorite posts table because that's a LEFT JOIN that may yield null values. I used the fiddle and got 8 rows, see answer below.

Comment: @RobP yes your query gets 8 rows however, it displays user # 1's friend's favourite. what I need is to only display user favourite posts, own posts and friend posts.

Comment: @IkoTikashi yes as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I went into the fiddle and realized you are running the friendship JOIN and WHERe stuff backwards. Friendship is a one-directional relationship. If you start from POSTS, that user may have me as a friend, but I may not have them as a friend.

In your example, only person 2 has person 1 as a friend, but persons 2 and 3 are both friends of 1. Hence your failure to get 8 rows.

This query yields 8 rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.title, p.post_id, p.user_id, fp.post_id
 FROM posts AS p
 LEFT OUTER JOIN favourite_posts AS fp
 ON p.post_id = fp.post_id
 JOIN users AS u
 ON p.user_id = u.user_id
 LEFT JOIN friendship AS f
 ON p.user_id = f.friend_id
 WHERE p.user_id = 1
 OR (f.user_id = 1
 AND f.status = 1)
```

Also note:
OR and AND have equal precedence and process from left to right. Try to be unambiguous with OR among ANDs, as it yields subtle errors:

```
 WHERE (p.user_id = 1
 OR f.friend_id = 1)
 AND fp.user_id = 1
 AND f.status = 1
```

with added parentheses. Otherwise your query is equivalent to:

```
 WHERE p.user_id = 1
 OR (f.friend_id = 1
 AND (fp.user_id = 1
 AND f.status = 1))
```

Also, you do a LEFT JOIN so fp could have null values. Is it actually what you meant to select only favorite posts? Should you actually mean this?

```
 WHERE p.user_id = 1
 OR (f.friend_id = 1
 AND f.status = 1)
```

Comment: You mean OR and AND have different precendence?

Comment: In my post, I need to get user # 1's all posts (including his friends' and favourite posts) so I want to display all posts. 8 in total. I chose LEFT join because I want to display both favourite and non-favourite posts.

Comment: see recent edit. You were missing posts from friend #3 in addition to losing some rows because of the fp.userid filter, because you need to look at friends of user 1, not users who have 1 as a friend.

Comment: Yes that's why I have a status field in Friendship. 1 means accepted. Otherwise, pending or declined

Comment: But just because 1 lists 3 as a friend doesn't mean 3 lists 1 as a friend. Clarify your intent here so we can get the logic right...

Comment: @RobP I've added user 3 and user 1 in the friendship table.

Comment: Are you saying that friendship WILL always be symmetric? (it isn't on all social media systems...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73091/discussion-between-betty-barnes-and-robp).